# How to document an endpoint with 2 path parameters using sails-hook-actions2-swagger?

Tags: swagger, sails.js, sails-hook

I'm using `@logisticinfotech/sails-hook-actions2-swagger` to document my REST API. My endpoint looks like this: `/ user /: uid / company /: cid`.
After generating the documentation, the company crashes between two IDs, which makes the endpoint look like this: `/ user /: uid /: cid`, which can't be left.
I can't fire this company to submit via Swagger UI.

My swagger.js:

```
'PUT /user/:uid/company/:cid':{action: 'userCompany/add',
            swagger: {
              summary: 'Add user to company',
              parameters: [{
                in: 'path',
                name: 'uid',
                required: true,
                type: 'string',
                description: 'User account ID'
              },
              {
                in: 'path',
                name: 'cid',
                required: true,
                type: 'string',
                description: 'Company ID'  
              }]
            }
          },
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What annotation library/framework do you use?

Comment: @Helen: ```@logisticinfotech/sails-hook-actions2-swagger```

Answer (score 0):

Your url setup should be defined as follows

```
   'PUT /user/{uid}/company/{cid}'
```

Then it will properly render the swagger